# Error while deploying Sinatra App on cloudfoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry

I tried deploying **Sinatra** app on **cloudfoundry**. I am getting following error:

```
$vmc push

Would you like to deploy from the current directory? [Yn]:
Application Name: myapp
Detected a Sinatra Application, is this correct? [Yn]:
Application Deployed URL [myapp.cloudfoundry.ctrls.com]:
Memory reservation (128M, 256M, 512M, 1G, 2G) [128M]:
How many instances? [1]:
Would you like to save this configuration? [yN]:
Creating Application: OK
Uploading Application:
  Checking for available resources: OK
  Packing application: OK
  Uploading (0K): OK  
Push Status: OK
Staging Application 'myapp': OK                                                
Starting Application 'myapp': .......**Error:
Application 'myapp's state is undetermined, not enough information available.**
```

If I run **vmc apps**, it does not show health of the application

```
$ vmc apps

+-------------+----+--------+------------------------------+----------+
| Application | #  | Health | URLS                         | Services |
+-------------+----+--------+------------------------------+----------+
| myapp       | 1  | N/A    | myapp.cloudfoundry.xxxxx.com |          |
+-------------+----+--------+------------------------------+----------+
```

When I manually started the app, I got app is already started

```
$vmc start myapp
Application 'myapp' already started
```

Following is the output of "vmc logs"

```
$vmc logs myapp

 Sinatra/1.2.1 has taken the stage on 26952 for production with backup from Thin
 Thin web server (v1.2.11 codename Bat-Shit Crazy)
 Maximum connections set to 1024
 Listening on 0.0.0.0:26952, CTRL+C to stop
```

If I try to restart the app, I get the same error posted above.

Please provide some workaround

Answer (score 1):

What URL are you using for the application? Currently, on cloudfoundry.com you can't use custom URLs, only ones that follow the pattern *.cloudfoundry.com

Comment: I am using cloudfoundry.mydomain.com. I set the target to api.cloudfoundry.mydomain.com

Comment: I changed it to the above format. still same issue. Is there anything else that  can be the cause for this?

Comment: For the sake of brevity, can you confirm that you are deploying to http://api.cloudfoundry.com?